# Need to drag and drop a file in html

Tags: javascript

I am having a html file containing a div tag. While viewing this html in browser, I want to drag a file from my desktop and drop it in this html file (in browser). Then the dragged file (ex. jpeg) path should display in the div portion. How to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't (AFAIK) be able to do that with pure JS in an HTML 4.0 environment.  You'll either need Silverlight, Flash or (heaven forbid) an ActiveX controller.  HTML 5.0 has DnD capabilities (I believe) but not all browsers suport it.

http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/

that should give you some idea about how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

What about pure HTML5? ;)
http://slides.html5rocks.com/#drag-in